# Heroku application error unable to trace logs

Tags: node.js, heroku

I deployed my small project to heroku server. Also run the `heroku ps:scale web=1` to add free dynos to run my project. but it seems there is some error I am not able to trace it. Please help.

[image: heroku logs]

Comment: just restart your dynos and try again

Comment: I would say your express router doesnt have a `GET /` route and you dont have a  handler for unexisting routes (404). Maybe you can show us your `app.js` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using this simple code.

Before my code was like

`const PORT = 3000;`

and after update

`const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;`

and it works. I don't understand it just port defining. But it resolved.

Answer (score 1):

In many environments (e.g. `Heroku`), and as a convention, you can set the environment variable `PORT` to tell your web server what port to listen on.

So `process.env.PORT || 3000` means: whatever is in the environment variable `PORT`, or `3000` if there's nothing there.

So you pass that `app.listen`, or to `app.set(port, ...),` and that makes your server be able to accept a parameter from the environment what port to listen on.

If you pass `3000` hard-coded to `app.listen()`, you're always listening on port `3000`, which might be just for you, or not, depending on your requirements and the requirements of the environment in which you're running your server.